# How can I have iCal email me reminders

Tags: email, ical

I have heard of people getting email reminders from iCal, but I can't figure out how to do it. So the obvious question is:

How do I have iCal email me reminders?

As I see now that was removed. In that case is there a widget to let me email reminders to myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what you are now looking for is an *Alert*.

From Yosemite **Calendar** help:

> ## Set event alerts and receive notifications
>
> Be notified of an upcoming Calendar event by setting one or more
>   alerts for it. An alert can place a notification on your screen, send
>   an email, or open a file.
>
> #### Set an alert for an event
>
> - Double-click an event, then click the event’s date.
> - Click next to Alert and do either of the following:
>
>   - Choose a time or day from the pop-up menu.
>   - Choose Custom and then choose one of the following options:
>   - Message: Displays a notification on the screen.
>   - Message with sound: Displays a notification on the screen and makes a sound.
>   - ***Email: Sends you an email.***

[image: Select Custom]

[image: Choose Email]

Answer (score 1):

The email reminder function was removed some time before iCal was renamed to Calendar. Presumably it was a security risk, but I can't find a good link explaining the exploits that used that pathway to harm people.